# Is it correct to have a table in SQL with just foreign key columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Is it correct to have a table in SQL with just foreign key columns? All columns are foreign keys, except the primary key `ID`.

Here is the scenario in my mind. I wanted to be sure first and then implemented it.

I have three tables => Personnel, Position, Place. Personnel table has general information of employees, Position table has different job positions and tasks in a company, Place table has info about different places in the city. So, an Agent is one of the personnel with one of the job tasks who should go to do the task in one of the places. Agents could change every week, select between personnel and give them almost randomly tasks and places.

Comment: Thats up to you - does it solve your design problem?

Comment: It is possible. But it depends on the actual design.

Comment: @Parham.D Share table definitions

Comment: Off-topic for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). A better solution is to educate yourself on data modelling. No one reading your question can tell you if your schema is "correct" if they don't know what system you are actually modelling (and know it very well).

Comment: What design method presentation are you following & where are you stuck in it? Otherwise you are just asking us to write yet another one. An SQL FK constraint says subrow values appear elsewhere as PK/UNIQUE; where that's so & not implied by other declarations, declare it. Dozens of information modeling & DB design textbooks are free online. Moreover this is an easily found faq. Eg google 'site:stackoverflow.com when should i declare a foreign key' etc etc. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS This topic is programming so is OK for [so], but otherwise I agree with SMor.

Comment: Because I am amateur in SQL I just wanted to know if a table with all foreign key columns are possible and correct or not. I realized in general it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you an example where it is perfectly correct and desired:

when you have many to many relationship, say `Table1` and `Table2` the best practice states that you should have table, eg. `Table1Table2` with just two columns: `Table1Id` and `Table2Id`, both foreign keys to respective tables and together they make primary key.

Having said that, it is perfectly correct, as long as it satisfies your design.

To say anything more, you should share your database schema.

Comment: Example: I have three tables => Personnel, Position, Place. Then in Agent table I have three foreign keys to these three tables. No more column in Agent table except ID. Is it correct in this example? appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a foreign key on the child table referencing the parent table so it is correct that all fields be foreign key but you have to have primary key on that table.